# What makes a System Property Parameter required in Teamcity?

Tags: parameters, teamcity

I am looking at two separate Teamcity templates.  Both have a system property called: system.Key

In the parameters section of one template it shows

```
system.Key  <value is required> undeletable
```

In another template it shows

```
system.Key <empty> delete
```

both templates have a build step where the script uses this property in the script like:

```
%system.Key%
```

So I am trying to understand why it is required in one template and not the other?

What else should I look at that would cause this?